# Can't instanciate DynamoDBStoreManager (because of incorrect Apache HTTP Client version?)

Tags: maven, amazon-dynamodb, apache-httpclient-4.x, titan

When I try to create a [TinkerPop Graph](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.2.3/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Graph.html) instance that connects to a (local) DynamoDB server, I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V
```

[Basic research](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/issues/44) suggests that the [Apache HTTP Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/project-reports.html) version used is too old (minimum [4.5.2 required](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/938)), but my project only imports the one version included by the `dynamodb` artifact itself:

[image: httpclient dependency introduced by dynamodb]

I've already cleaned the project, deleted my entire `.m2` folder and let Maven update the project. Can I check the actual version used during runtime? What else could it be?

---

#### Details

Full stack trace of the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreManager
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:55)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:473)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:407)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1320)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:62)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:44)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.<init>(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.getPreferredSocketFactory(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:92)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:65)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:58)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:51)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:39)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:314)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:298)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:165)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:154)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.<init>(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:264)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.<init>(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:239)
    at com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBDelegate.<init>(DynamoDBDelegate.java:174)
    at com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.Client.<init>(Client.java:145)
    at com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreManager.<init>(DynamoDBStoreManager.java:90)
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trust Occam's razor: The simplest answer is likely the correct one. I had manually linked a `.jar` file that was including an older version of the Apache HTTP Client. It works now that I got rid of it.